# Creating csv file in Scala

Tags: json, scala, opencsv

I am trying to to create a `csv` file in Scala by getting data in the form of JsValue from a third part API.
My method to save data to CSV file is :

```
def saveToCSV(str:Seq[JsValue]) = {
  val outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Result.csv"))
  val csvWriter = new CSVWriter(outputFile)
    val data = str.head
    data match {
      case JsObject(fields) => {
        var listOfRecords = new ListBuffer[Array[String]]()
        //val csvFields = Array("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume")
        //listOfRecords += csvFields
        fields.values.foreach(value => {
          val jsObject = value.asJsObject()
          val nameList = List(jsObject.fields("1. open").toString,jsObject.fields("2. high").toString,jsObject.fields("3. low").toString,jsObject.fields("4. close").toString,jsObject.fields("5. volume").toString)
          listOfRecords += Array(nameList.toString)
          csvWriter.writeAll(listOfRecords.toList.asInstanceOf)
          println("Written!")
          outputFile.close()
        })
      }
      case JsNull => println("Null")
    }
```

In the above code on line **`**csvWriter.writeAll(listOfRecords.toList.asInstanceOf)**`** I am getting this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to class scala.runtime.Nothing$ (scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon and scala.runtime.Nothing$ are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

On removing *asInstanceOf* from `csvWriter.writeAll(listOfRecords.toList.asInstanceOf)` this line, I get a compile time error on *writeAll()* method saying that it expects parameter of type *util.List[Array[String]]*

Could anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code.

1. `asJsObject()` is a method that does not exist in `JsValue`. Instead you should use `value.as[JsObject]`.
2. `jsObject.fields` is of type `Seq[(String, JsValue)]`, so you can't call `jsObject.fields("1. open")`. Instead you should call: `jsObject("1. open").toString`
3. Calling `listOfRecords.toList.asInstanceOf` returns `null`. You should specify what you want to convert it to. But in order to convert it into a java type, you can just call: `listOfRecords.toList.asJava`. Don't forget: `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`

The complete method is:

```scala
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter
import play.api.libs.json.{JsNull, JsObject, JsValue}

import java.io.{BufferedWriter, FileWriter}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

def saveToCSV(str: Seq[JsValue]) = {
  val outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Result.csv"))
  val csvWriter = new CSVWriter(outputFile)
  val data = str.head
  data match {
    case JsObject(fields) => {
      var listOfRecords = new ListBuffer[Array[String]]()
      //val csvFields = Array("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume")
      //listOfRecords += csvFields
      fields.values.foreach(value => {
        val jsObject = value.as[JsObject]
        val nameList = List(jsObject("1. open").toString, jsObject("2. high").toString, jsObject("3. low").toString, jsObject("4. close").toString, jsObject("5. volume").toString)
        listOfRecords += Array(nameList.toString)
        csvWriter.writeAll(listOfRecords.toList.asJava)
        println("Written!")
        outputFile.close()
      })
    }
    case JsNull => println("Null")
  }
}
```

This will work under the assumption that the head of `str` contains a JsObject, with the fields:

- "1. open"
- "2. high"
- "3. low"
- "4. close"

Are you deliberately taking only the first element of the input to this function? Please note that `str.head` is unsafe, in case the sequence is empty.

Comment: Thanks. Now while calling this method I am using following code: val str = EntityUtils.toString(entity,"UTF-8") val jsonParser = Json.parse(str) SaveService.saveToCSV(jsonParser.as[JsObject].fields(1). Can you help me how can I now modify the code that you have sent above?